# How to stop a page loading 1000's of images at once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, performance, batch-file

We have been building online catalogs for motorcycle parts for our online store.

Originally we did this with a program that turned PDF's into flash catalogs, but flash can't run on a lot of devices as you know and these devices are now getting super common.

So we have build an alternative in HTML, we exported each page of the original PDF's into images and built them into a jquery book.

http://www.thehogfathermotorcycles.com/catalog/jcata/mag.php?a=cce&b=2014&c=1

Some of these catalogs (like the one above) is over 1000 pages. I think you see the problem coming by now.... How on earth do we stop all 1000 images loading at once?

In a perfect world we load say 20... as the user flips through the catalog new images load on the back of this 20.

I really am stumped with this, how would you do it? We tried lazy load but unless you are scrolling vertically it does not work.

any help would be seriously appreciated.

Comment: Surely you have some variable holding the currently viewed page? Why don't you alter your lazy load function to look at that variable, and do the same magic there ?

Comment: Have you tried [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer? Don’t add thousands of images to a HTML page.

More verbose, helpful answer: You could create a PHP script where you paginate the catalogue items, and then use AJAX to load the next “page” via pagination links. Destroy the previous page, replace with the next requested page.

Comment: the best way but also the most time intensive one would be to build the pages new from scratch since pdf to html often is dirty